# ProcessPoolExecutor logging fails to log inside function on Windows but not on Unix / Mac

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

When I run the following script on a Windows computer, I do not see any of the log messages from the `log_pid` function, however I do when I run on Unix / Mac. I've read before that multiprocessing is different on Windows compared to Mac, but it's not clear to me what changes should I make to get this script to work on Windows. I'm running Python 3.6.

```
import logging
import sys
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os


def log_pid(x):
    logger.info('Executing on process: %s' % os.getpid())


def do_stuff():
    logger.info('this is the do stuff function.')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        executor.map(log_pid, range(0, 10))


def main():
    logger.info('this is the main function.')
    do_stuff()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logger.info('Start of script ...')

    main()

    logger.info('End of script ...')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unix processes are created via the [`fork`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) strategy where the child gets cloned from the parent and continues its execution right at the moment the parent forked.

On Windows is quite different: a blank process is created and a new Python interpreter gets launched. The interpreter will then load the module where the `log_pid` function is located and execute it.

This means the `__main__` section is not executed by the newly spawned child process. Hence, the `logger` object is not created and the `log_pid` function crashes accordingly. You don't see the error because you ignore the result of your computation. Try to modify the logic as follows.

```
def do_stuff():
    logger.info('this is the do stuff function.')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        iterator = executor.map(log_pid, range(0, 10))
        list(iterator)  # collect the results in a list
```

And the issue will become evident.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 175, in _process_worker
    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 153, in _process_chunk
    return [fn(*args) for args in chunk]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 153, in <listcomp>
    return [fn(*args) for args in chunk]
  File "C:\Users\cafama\Desktop\pool.py", line 8, in log_pid
    logger.info('Executing on process: %s' % os.getpid())
NameError: name 'logger' is not defined
```

When dealing with process pools (whether `concurrent.futures` or `multiprocessing` ones) always collect the result of the computation to avoid silent bugs to cause confusion.

To fix the problem, just move the `logger` creation at the top level of the module and everything will work on all platforms.

```
import logging
import sys
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)   

def log_pid(x):
    logger.info('Executing on process: %s' % os.getpid())

...
```

Comment: This works for me on Linux but not on Windows unfortunately :(